# Using anchor tags when header element uses fixed position

Tags: jquery, html, css, anchor, fixed

The header position is fixed and is 100px tall.

There are anchor tags within the header that goto content. The problem is because of the header when its clicked it doesnt scroll to the correct place. i.e. it scrolls to far.

How can I add vertical space (padding) to that anchor position so it shows correctly?

my code

link:

```
<li>
  <a href="#whoisresponsible">text</a>
</li>
```

anchor:

```
<h3>
  <a name="whoisresponsible"></a>Q:&nbsp; Who is responsible for Lifeline’s Suburban Garage Sales?
</h3>
```

here is a js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/lmeyer/XqLRg/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery(".link").on("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var name= jQuery(this).attr("href");
    var n=name.split("#"); 

    var element = jQuery('[name="'+n[1]+'"]') 
    var container = jQuery("#mainContainer");


    var number = element.offset().top - container.offset().top + container.scrollTop() -190;
    jQuery(document).scrollTop(number);



});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This instead
http://jsfiddle.net/TDPP4/

Add CSS classes to h3 and a

```
<h3 class="Head3">
  <a class="InLink" name="whoisresponsible"></a>Q:&nbsp; Who is responsible for Lifeline’s   Suburban Garage Sales?
</h3>
```

Then add this CSS

```
.Head3{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;    
}
a.InLink{
     position:absolute;
     margin-top:-150px;
}
```

Comment: i do not think that is the answer - i would think you need to do a js that when clicked on moved to anchor then adds/subtracts height of header to get correct position

Comment: The question was how to "add vertical space(padding)".. I think JS will be too much for that simple issue

Comment: but if you add a br in the content its still going to go to the wrong place. the problem is the fixed hearder surely?!

Comment: Why the header has to be like this?

Comment: The header has to remain fixed.

Comment: Could you post the sample on jsFiddle

Comment: I've added more links and still looks fine, check this http://jsfiddle.net/TDPP4/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure my answer is correct, because i'm  really not understand what your problem.

Set the position of the heading target to be :

`relative` or `absolute`

then when the anchor link clicked you set the position of the target where it is must to stop

Comment: i'm just use padding for that, because your markup.. check this.. http://jsfiddle.net/YsL86/6/